# Problem in type casting in NSDate to NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, type-conversion

I developing an application, in which i found a ridiculous problem in type casting, I am not able to type cast `NSDate` to `NSString`.

```
NSDate *selected =[datePicker date];
NSString *stringTypeCast = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:selected
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

From ,above snippet datePicker is an object of `UIDatePickerController`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method would be:

`NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithString:[selected description]]`

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/description).

Another would be:

`NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selected]`

See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:).

A more appropriate method would be:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selected];
[dateFormatter release];
```

This will automatically return the date in a string formatted to the user's local date format. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/stringFromDate:).

Comment: Here i am using
NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", selected];
but i am able to get the date into string with time attached , now i just want date not time so how do i do that plz suggest me for that, And thanks for the solution...

Comment: That is functionally equivalent to the first method I mentioned. In other words, you are only going to get back what the `description` method of the NSDate object is written to return. If you want a specific format then you need to use an NSDateFormatter and specify the desired format string.

Answer (score 4):

Use [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert NSDate objects to NSString objects.  Type conversion is different from type casting.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do this.  What you really want to do is to use an [`NSDateFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to properly convert the `NSDate` into an `NSString`.  Going about this any other way is Not Correct™.

Answer (score 0):

The method you use requires NSData, not NSDate, that's why it doesn't work.